# How to get reference of the component (componentRef)?

Tags: angular, angular13

I have an issue about detect the ComponentRef.
I create a Dynamic Component via ViewContainerRef inside ComponentA and append after app-root. I can get the reference of this component by
`const componentRef = ViewContainerRef.createComponent(DynamicComponent)`
This Dynamic Component will still be there when ComponentA destroy.
I want to control that DynamicComponent (change variables, manual destroy it) but when ComponentA destroy, I dont have any idea to get that componentRef anymore.

I found a solution for this issue. I assign that componentRef to a variable in AppComponent and use ApplicationRef to get it. I can do it because AppComponent will not be destroyed. But it is not a good solution.
How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [creating a service](https://angular.io/guide/creating-injectable-service#creating-an-injectable-service-1) for this. That way you can inject the service in other components

Here is the general idea

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DynamicComponentService {
    componentRef: ComponentRef

    setComponentRef(ref) {
        this.componentRef = ref
    }

    getComponentRef() {
        return this.componentRef
    }
}
```

```
@Component({
  // ...
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit {
    
    // Inject the component service
    constructor(private dynamicComponentService: DynamicComponentService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        // Get the component ref
        this.dynamicComponentService.getComponentRef()
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is a better way. But seems Angular dont have any method to find componentRef without directly assigning after created component.

Comment: Can you not save this reference after creation using the service?

Comment: Yes I can. I mean I want to find a way to detect componentRef, like we can find any element in DOM.